# Read several byte from file via http c#

Tags: c#, http

How to download first 200 bytes of a file via HTTP protocol using C#?
I believed it could be done like this:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
byte[] buffer = new byte[200];
using (var stream = wc.OpenRead(fileName))
{
     stream.Read(buffer, 0, 200);
}
```

but when `wc.OpenRead` it called it downloads the whole file.

Comment: @Jon: No, that's certainly not a duplicate as this is C# and the other is Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set a Range Header on your WebClient before you invoke the OpenRead method.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers.aspx

Comment: Could you please provide a source how to do it. I tried `wc.Headers.Add("Range", "bytes=0-200");` but `wc.OpenRead(fileName)` throws an exception.

Comment: What is the exception being thrown, please?

Comment: I did what I needed using WebRequest.